# What is the exception contract for the .NET Google.Cloud.Firestore API?

Tags: .net, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Google's .NET Firestore library [documents its API](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/index), but leaves out any information about its exception behaviour.

Is there any reference for what "line of business" exceptions can be thrown by the API? For example,

- if I await `FirestoreDbBuilder.BuildAsync()` without valid authentication available
- if I await `FirestoreDbBuilder.BuildAsync()` without network available
- if the network is down when I await `CollectionReference.GetSnapshotAsync()`
- if the network goes down while listening to `CollectionReference.Listen(Action<QuerySnapshot>, CancellationToken)`

I'm not especially concerned by "malformed executable" exceptions, like what happens if someone deletes the library DLLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid there's no policy document for this.

In general though:

- When making gRPC calls (like `GetSnapshotAsync` does) I'd expect an `RpcException` to be thrown
- When calling `BuildAsync`, it very much depends on the credentials:

  - When using default credentials, if the credentials are present in the
    form of a JSON file, no network is needed but `InvalidOperationException` [will be thrown](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/main/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/DefaultCredentialProvider.cs#LL111C35-L111C60) if the file is invalid JSON or does not represent valid credential parameters
  - If the credentials are passed directly, just calling `BuildAsync` doesn't do anything with the credentials immediately

Additionally, if you don't specify the project ID in the builder, `BuildAsync` will need to ascertain that automatically - which ends up throwing `ArgumentNullException` when constructing the actual `FirestoreDb`. (That's possibly not ideal; I can see us potentially changing that to `InvalidOperationException` in a later version - probably in a major version bump though.)